Unexpected Behavior of electric-indent-mode with Java
When I'm defining variables in my code with electric-indent-mode enabled, after pressing the RET key, the cursor is left 4 spaces behind the expected indentation. It's not until I place the semicolon (;) at the end of the variable that it indents correctly. Is this the normal behavior of electric-indent-mode?
public abstract class Animal {
        private String nombre;
        private int edad;
        private boolean esDomestico;
    cursor pos
}

This is the line I use to activate electric-indent-mode:
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #' electric-indent-mode)

